# Order of $\phi(g)$ divides the order of $g$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $\phi: G \to H$ be a group homomorphism, and let $g$ be an element of $G$. Show that the order of $\phi(g)$ divides the order of $g$.

Comment: ...please...?? And what did you try?

Comment: Of course, one has to work separately in the case in which $\langle g\rangle\cong\mathbb Z$ is infinite.

Answer (score 3):

Let $n=|g|, \nu = |\phi(g)|$. Since $g^n = e$ and $\phi(g^n) = \phi(g)^n$, we have $\nu \le n$.

Enormous hint: If $\nu \not\mid n$, write $n=k \nu +r$, with $r < \nu$.

The details:

> Then $e=\phi(g)^n = (\phi(g)^\nu)^k \phi(g)^r = \phi(g)^r$, which contradicts the definition of $\nu$. Hence $\nu \mid n$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** If $g^n = e_G$, then $e_H = \phi(g^n) = \phi(g)^n$.

Comment: Hint = Complete solution.

Comment: Hmmm...not quite, @MartinBrandenburg: as a beginner the OP *still* has to deduce some stuff about the relation between that $\,n\,$ and *the order* of $\,\phi(g)\,$ . Certainly a huge hint, but not yet the whole solution, imo. +1

Answer (score 2):

let $o(g) = n$ for $g\in G$ $\implies$ $g^{n} = e$<sub>G</sub>

Now $\phi(g^{n}) = \phi(g)^{n}$ using group homomorphism property

as $\phi(g^{n}) = e$<sub>H</sub> $\implies \phi(g)^{n} = e$<sub>H</sub>

$\implies o(\phi(g)) <= n$ and $o(\phi(g))$ divides n