# Basic Abstract Algebra - Homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Given a homomorphism $f:G \rightarrow H$, $G$ finitely generated, what can you say about the order of $g_i$ and $f(g_i)$?

I've thought about this question for a while but haven't come to a conclusion.

If we consider the natural homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_3$, the order of 1 in $\mathbb{Z}$ is infinite but the order of 1 in $\mathbb{Z}_3$ is only $3$. Therefore, the order of $f(g_i)$ can be less than that of $g_i$. But can't it also be greater? If not, wouldn't it be impossible to construct homomorphisms from a group of order $n$ to a group of order $p$ where $p > n$?

Thanks.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/356597/order-of-phig-divides-the-order-of-g

Comment: If both groups are finite, you can say that the order of $f(g_i)$ divides the order of $g_i$.

Comment: @ChrisLeary: we don't need either group to be finite, only that $g$ has finite order (otherwise the statement doesn't make sense).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to show that:
$$f(1_G)=1_H$$
$$f(g^n)=f(g)^n$$
So:
$$g^k=1_G \implies f(g)^k=1_H$$
Hence if a $g \in G$ has finite order $k$, then $f(g)$ has order dividing $k$.

Comment: $f(g)$ has order *dividing* $k$

Comment: @user115654 whoops, fixed.

Comment: Thanks Dror. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $f(a^n)=f(a)^n$. If $m$ is the order of $a$, $1=f(1)=f(a^m)=f(a)^m$. What do you conclude?

Comment: I appreciate the help.